# Assuming finite Radon-Nikodym to prove sigma-finite

Tags: functional-analysis, radon-nikodym

Suppose that we assume the version of Radon-Nikodym for finite measure that is if $X$ is some set, $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ and $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite measures on $X$ where $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ then we can find a nonnegative integrable function such that

$$\nu(E) = \int_E gd{\mu}.$$

**I was wondering if we could argue as follows in the case where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite:**

Let $\{A_n\}_n$ be a sequence over $\mathcal{A}$ such that $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$, $\mu(A_{n+1})<\infty$, $\nu(A_{n+1})<\infty$ and $\cup_n A_n = X$.

Then by applying the finite version of Radon-Nikodyn to the case where we restrict our measures to $A_n$ we obtain a sequence of functions $\{g_n\}_n$ where $g_n:A_n\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ and for any $\mathcal{A}\ni E\subset A_n$

$$\nu(E) = \int_E g_n d\mu.$$

We extend each $g_n$ to be zero outside of $A_n$.

**Claim:** $g_n\leq g_{n+1}$ almost everywhere. Let $E = \{x\in A_n\mid g_n(x)>g_{n+1}(x)\}$ then

$$\nu(E) =\int_{E}g_{n}d\mu>\int_{E}g_{n+1}d\mu=\nu(E)$$
which implies that $\mu(E) = 0\Rightarrow \nu(E) =0$. Now define

$$g = \lim_n g_n$$

then by the monotone convergence theorem

$$\nu(E) = \lim_n \int_E g_nd\mu = \int_E gd\mu.$$

My question is whether this reasoning is valid?

Comment: Side comment: I would spend a couple of words more on the sequence $\{ A_n\}$. Of course $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma-$finite, but we do not know a priori if they are with the same "decomposition" of the space...

Comment: You are right I need to think about this!

Comment: I guess we could do the following and correct me if I am wrong. Let $\{A_n\}$ and $\{B_n\}$ be increasing sequences such that  their union is both $X$ and $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ and $\nu(B_n)<\infty$. Consider $\{C_n\}$ given by $C_n = A_n\cap B_n$. This sequence is increasing and its union is all of $X$. Also each element of the sequence has finite measure with respect to both measures.

Comment: I do not see that $ \bigcup  C_n = X $ (also you should say something about indexing, because we do not even know if $C_n$ is nonempty). But what about taking $ C_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \cap  \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i$? This should work.

Comment: Well both sequences are increasing and since $\cup_n A_n = X = \cup_n B_n$ we can for every $x\in X$ find $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $x\in A_{n_1}$ and $x\in B_{n_2}$ but if $n = \max\{n_1,n_2\}$ then since the sequences are increasing $x\in A_{n}\cap B_{n}$

Comment: Your suggestion does not however assume that the sequences are increasing but I see that it should work as well

Comment: Alright, I agree that $C_n = A_n \cap B_n$ does the job!

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I did not see this the first time I thought about this problem